# Expressing trace semantics as a solution for a fixpoint equation

Tags: obfuscation, program-analysis

I was reading through the chapter on Obfuscation in "Practical Reverse Engineering" I encountered the following statement.

> Where X is the set of execution traces (finite and infinite), you can
>   express the trace semantics as the least solution (for the
>   computational partial ordering) of a fixpoint equation X = F( X).

Could someone explain what that means in simple terms? If you could point me towards any resources for further reading and learning, that'd be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consult pages 39-41 in the thesis

> "Code Obfuscation and Malware Detection by Abstract Interpretation"

of M. Dalla Preda about formal obfuscation; or sections 4.4 and 4.5 in the orignal paper

> "Systematic Design of Program Transformation Frameworks by Abstract
>   Interpretation"

of Cousot and Cousot.

The theory is formal and requires much more technical details than the following interpretation, but the idea is that:

The "finite trace" semantics of a program `P` is defined by the set of all finite traces of `P`. A trace is nothing but a finite sequence of states of `P`, obtained when running `P`, step-by-step over "commands" of `P`.

(You may note that, from a state, we can get a set of possible next states, because the command at this state can be nondeterministic: it can receive some value from environment).

To calculate the finite trace semantics of `P`, one way (which one is refered in your book) is to use a function `F` defined from FinSeqs to FinSeqs:

```
F : FinSeq -> FinSeq
```

where `FinSeqs` is the set of all "sub-set of finite sequences of states of `P`" (you may think that each sub-set is a possible value for the "finite trace" semantics of `P`).

This function `F` map a sub-set `X` to a sub-set `X'` so that each trace `x'` of `X'` has a trace `x` of `X` as suffix (that is the reason why it is called "backward" in the paper of Cousot and Cousot). Particularly, we have that

```
x' = sj . x
x = si . x1
```

and `sj` must be able to be a next state of `si`. The least fixpoint of the function `F`, namely some set `Xp` so that

```
F(Xp) = Xp
```

is called the trace semantics of `P`.